# Slow form submission and configuring request timeout

Tags: testing, cypress, timeout, e2e, cypress-intercept

I'm using Cypress for End-to-End testing.

Problem 1: Slow Form Submission

When I submit a form, the associated POST request returns a 200 status code.
However, there's a significant delay when using Cypress. Normally, form submission takes 7-8 seconds, but with Cypress, it takes more than 20 seconds. What might be causing this delay, and how can I optimize it?

Problem 2: Cypress timeout for request and response

I've noticed that Cypress has built-in timeouts for requests and responses.
In my tests, I need to wait for a specific request to complete and for a certain response status code before proceeding.

Cypress allows for defining a maximum wait time for requests (e.g., 25 seconds as configured in my Cypress configuration file), but I need Cypress to wait until the request is responded to with a status code.

How can I configure Cypress to wait until the request receives a specific status code before proceeding?

[image]

Comment: You added the test code in a picture, please don't do that. Instead, copy and paste the text of the test code to the question.

Comment: Also, it's fairly meaningless without being able to see the HTML page against which you are testing. Please also paste the **text** of the relevant HTML page into the question.

Comment: The question makes no sense, why not increase the timeout?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [cy.wait()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Arguments) command, there is a `responseTimeout` option which overrides the global `responseTimeout` for this particular request.

So, what should work is

```js
cy.wait('@postVehicle', {responseTimeout: 30_000}).then(...
```

As for optimization, that's a lot harder to diagnose remotely from just the test code, however if it's server-related you can get an immediate response by mocking the response in the intercept.

```js
cy.intercept('POST', 'backend/vehicle', {<mock response here>})
  .as('postVehicle)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do not want to override the global timeout. What i am trying to achieve is that keep waiting until a response comes back. I don't to set a fix time. Will I need to make something like a promise then on my own?